# Get real IP from Request in server

Tags: go, docker-network

I am trying to extract the real IP from the HTTP request. When I make a CURL call from a container deployed on the same VM, I get the IP of the container from the http Request instead of IP of the VM through r.RemoteAddr.

But when I print the request using `fmt.Printf("Request: %s", r)` I can see the real IP of the VM is there. The sample request from Print statement looks like:

`&{GET /containers/json HTTP/1.1 %!s(int=1) %!s(int=1) map[Accept:[*/*] User-Agent:[curl/7.64.0]] {} %!s(func() (io.ReadCloser, error)=<nil>) %!s(int64=0) [] %!s(bool=false) 10.32.20.122:2375 map[] map[] %!s(*multipart.Form=<nil>) map[] 172.20.0.1:47102 /containers/json %!s(*tls.ConnectionState=<nil>) %!s(<-chan struct {}=<nil>) %!s(*http.Response=<nil>) %!s(*context.cancelCtx=&{0xc000120480 {0 0} <nil> map[] <nil>})}`

In the above output `10.32.20.122` is the VM IP and `172.20.0.1` is docker network gateway IP. I want to extract the VM IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using `%+v` in your Printf

```
fmt.Printf("Request: %+v", r)
```

Then you could see what the field is called.